# Turning off/on thermostat based on temp. and if it's raining or not

Tags: swift, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
let temperature = 45
if temperature < 68 {
print("off")
}else {
print("on")
}
```

^^that is what I have so far, however I'm not sure how to add the isRaining and isOn properties to this code? And apparently the printed statement is meant to come out to be

```
true | false
```

or that's what it says when I try to turn in the assignment.. I've only been doing coding for about a week now so I'm really sorry if I sound dumb haha but any help would be awesome!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically [how to ask for homework help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Basically, you need to try something, get an error and ask for help to get past it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this code, can help you, you can try on a playgraund

```
let temperature = 45.0

func checkTemperature(temp: Double) -> Bool{
     if temp < 68{
         return false
     }
     else{
         return true
     }
}

let isOn = checkTemperature(temp: temperature)

if isOn{
   print("on")
}
else{
   print("off")
}
```

if you have doubts, please tell me.